# Can't format USB with Disks in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount

I think I have a broken USB.
 It won't show up in the File manager and even not in GParted, just in the Disks Application preinstalled in Ubuntu 18.10.
 It says, that the stick is mounted on `/dev/sdb` but if I try to `cd` into that directory with the Terminal, it won't work. And if I want to format it with the Disks Application, I can't! The option is greyed out! I can just click on "Edit Mount Options..." Could someone please help me?

Comment: You can analyze the problem, and if you are lucky, make the USB drive work again, according to the tips at the following link, [Can't format my usb drive. I have already tried with mkdosfs and gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)

Comment: No, `/dev/sdb/` is not a mount point, it is a disk that holds partitions `/dev/sdb1`, `/dev/sdb2`, etc. You can only access the file system on a partition if you mount it to a mount point. Typically, a mount point is something like `/media/username/mydisk`. The mount is supposed to be performed automatically when you plug in the drive, but for some reason, this has not happened. This does not mean that your drive is faulty. The fact that you can see something at `/dev/sdb` is good news.

Comment: `lsblk` wont Display the USB just `sda1` mounted on `/boot/efi` and `sda2` mounted on `/`  but `lsusb` displays it as `Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive`. I'm very confused...

Comment: Does it show up in Disks as "No Media" or something? That probably means it's beyond repair (lsusb detects the USB controller only, not the actual flash memory).

Comment: It shows up as Generic USB Flash Disk with the Volumes called 'No media'

Comment: I have never had luck fixing a flash drive with such symptoms. What kind of warranty does it have? Some companies are making really cheap large flash drives only good for a few writes. Sounds like Alcor Micro Corp, has a bad reputation according to Google.